# How to implement "remember me" using ServiceStack authentication

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I am trying to implement a **Remember me** feature in a ServiceStack-based project. I don't want to use Basic Authentication because it requires storing password in clear text in a browser cookie, so I need to come up with an alternative approach that will be easy to maintain and customized to my existing database.

I understand that ServiceStack's own support for **Remember me** is based on caching the `IAuthSession` instance in the server-side cache, which by default is an in-memory data structure that is wiped out when the website restarts (not good). Alternatively, the cache can also be based on Redis or Memcached, which is better (cached data survives website restarts) but adds more moving parts to the picture than I care to add to it.

Instead, I would like to implement the this functionality using my own database:

Table **Users**:

- UserID (auto-incremented identity)
- Username
- Password
- Email
- Name
- etc...

Table **Sessions**:

- SessionID (auto-incremented identity)
- UserID (FK to Users)
- StartDateTime
- EndDateTime
- SessionKey (GUID)

The way I see things working is this:

On login request, `AuthService` creates an empty instance of my `UserAuthSession` class (implements `IAuthSession`) and calls my custom credentials provider's `TryAuthenticate` method, which authenticates the user against the *Users* table, populates `UserAuthSession` with relevant user data and inserts a new record into the *Session* table.

Then the auth session is cached in the in-memory cache and ServiceStack session cookies (`ss-id` and `ss-pid`) are created and sent to the browser.

If the user checks **Remember me** then additionally my custom credential provider's `OnAuthenticate` method creates a permanent login cookie that contains the user's username and the auto-generated *Sessions.SessionKey*.  This cookie will help us track the user on subsequent visits even if the auth session is no longer in the cache.

Now, suppose the site has been restarted, the cache is gone, so when our user returns to the site his auth session is nowhere to be found. The current logic in `AuthenticateAttribute` redirects the user back to the login screen, but instead I want to change the flow so as to to try to identify the user based on my custom login cookie, i.e.:

1. look up the latest *Sessions* record for the username extracted from the login cookie
2. check if its *SessionKey* matches the key in the login cookie
3. if they match, then:

   - read the user's data from the *Users* table
   - create my custom auth session instance, fill it with user data and cache it (just like at initial login)
   - insert a new *Sessions* record with a new *SessionKey* value
   - send back to the browser a new login cookie to be used next time
4. if the keys don't match then send the user back to the login screen.

Does the above logic make sense?

Has anyone already implemented anything similar using ServiceStack?

If I were to proceed with this approach, what is the best course of action that doesn't involve creating my own custom version of `AuthenticateAttribute`?  I.e. which hooks can I use to build this using the existing ServiceStack code?

Comment: There are so many things wrong with your assumption how sessions in ServiceStack work. First off, Basic Authentication does not store the password in a cookie on the client-side, `ss-pid` is the permanent cookie that is created any way (but not used for retrieving the session key in non-permanent mode). Anyway, just use OrmLiteCacheClient.

Answer (score 3):

This is already built for you!  Just use the [OrmLiteCacheClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching).

In your `AppHost.Configure()` method, add this:

```cs
var dbCacheClient = new OrmLiteCacheClient {
    DbFactory = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()
};
dbCacheClient.InitSchema();
container.Register<ICacheClient>(dbCacheClient);
```

I am not sure when this particular feature was added, perhaps it wasn't available when you originally asked.  It's available in v4.0.31 at least.